# Wait for Input before continuing - Arduino Uno

Tags: c, open-source, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm making a basic sports game scorer (Squash/Racketball) using an Arduino Uno.

The aim is, 2 buttons, 1 player each has a button that they can increment the score with.
That's simple enough, however if & when both players happen to get to 10[score] at the same time they need to choose to either go to 13 or 15.

My problem is that it's listening to the last button pressed before calling the `scoreDecide()` func.

Eg, player1 was on 9(left button), player2 was on 10(right button).

player1 pressed their left button taking them up to 10, `scoreDecide()` was automatically called as loop recognised it was 10/10[score].

player2 decided to press right button, choosing 15 as score, but it's actually already chosen the left button value as that was the last one pressed before calling the `scoreDecide()` func, meaning 13 is actually being set as `target`, and pressing the right button is actually incrementing player2's score.

My code is as follows, I've spent 8 hours so far but I'm a complete novice to Arduino and having no luck.

```
        // Squash Scorer, by @MrWigster
        // Squash scoring is fairly easy for the most part, however at 10-10 the first player to have reached 10 must decide whether to play until 13 or 15, as the winner must always have a 2 point lead.
        // For this reason we need to include logic to let the players choose what score to play until.
        #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
        LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
        //Setting up Switches, 1 for each player to press.
        const int switchPlayer1 = 7;
        const int switchPlayer2 = 6;
        //Setting up LEDs, 1 representing each player.
        const int led1 = 9;
        const int led2 = 10;
        //Players names
        String player1 = "Bob";
        String player2 = "Alex";
        //Sets up initial values for switches
        int switchStatePlayer1 = 0;
        int switchStatePlayer2 = 0;
        int prevSwitchState1 = 0;
        int prevSwitchState2 = 0;

        int p1score = 0;
        int p2score = 0;
        int winner;
        // Initial Target score to get to
        int target = 10;

        void setup() {
            lcd.begin(16,2);
            pinMode(switchPlayer1,INPUT);
            pinMode(switchPlayer2,INPUT);
            pinMode(led1,OUTPUT);
            pinMode(led2,OUTPUT);
            lcd.print(player1);
            lcd.print(" Vs ");
            lcd.print(player2);
            lcd.setCursor(0,1);
            lcd.print("SquashScorer 0.1");
        }

        void loop() {
            // If LED is still on, turn it off.
            if((digitalRead(led1) == HIGH) || (digitalRead(led2) == HIGH)){
                delay(200);
            digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
            }
            // If players scores are the same, and it's at the target score to change
            if ((p1score == p2score) && (p1score == target)){
                // Where we call the new target deciding function
                delay(50); // Trying to give time for button to reset???
                target = scoreDecide(); // Main code that isn't working
            }
            if ((target == 15) || (target == 13) || (target == 10)) {
                switchStatePlayer1 = digitalRead(switchPlayer1);
                if (switchStatePlayer1 != prevSwitchState1){
                    if(switchStatePlayer1 == HIGH){
                        digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
                        p1score = p1score++;
                        //Deciding if this was winning point
                        if (
                                (p1score == target +1) || (p2score == target +1)
                                && (p1score != p2score)
                            ) {
                            winner = whoWins(player1);
                        }
                        // Writes the new score on the board
                        newScore();
                    }
                }
                prevSwitchState1 = switchStatePlayer1;

                switchStatePlayer2 = digitalRead(switchPlayer2);
                if (switchStatePlayer2 != prevSwitchState2){
                    if(switchStatePlayer2 == HIGH){
                        digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
                        p2score = p2score++;
                        //Deciding if this was winning point
                        if (
                                (p1score == target +1) || (p2score == target +1)
                                && (p1score != p2score)
                            ) {
                            winner = whoWins(player2);
                        }
                        // Writes the new score on the board
                        newScore();
                    }
                }
                prevSwitchState2 = switchStatePlayer2;
            }
        }

        // Let the player(s) decide which score to go up to, either 13 or 15.
        int scoreDecide() { // This function doesn't seem to work, its already getting a value before the player gets to choose, based on whatever player last reached TARGET.
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            // Give the players the info about which score they can choose
            lcd.print(target + 3);
            lcd.print("    OR    ");
            lcd.print(target + 5);
            switchStatePlayer1 = digitalRead(switchPlayer1);
            if (switchStatePlayer1 != prevSwitchState1){
                if(switchStatePlayer1 == LOW){
                    target = target + 3;
                    delay(1000);
                    return target;
                }
            }
            prevSwitchState1 = switchStatePlayer1;

            switchStatePlayer2 = digitalRead(switchPlayer2);
            if (switchStatePlayer2 != prevSwitchState2){
                if(switchStatePlayer2 == LOW){
                    target = target + 5;
                    delay(1000);
                    return target;
                }
            }
            prevSwitchState2 = switchStatePlayer2;

        }
        void newScore(){
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("Bob      Alex");
            lcd.setCursor(0,1);
            lcd.print(p1score);
            lcd.print(" Target:");
            lcd.print(target);
            lcd.print("  ");
            lcd.print(p2score);
        }
        void ledflash(){
            for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
                digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
                digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
                delay(500);
                digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
                delay(500);
            }
            digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
        }
        int whoWins(String player){
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print(player);
            lcd.setCursor(0,1);
            lcd.print("is the Winner!");
            ledflash();ledflash();
            delay(10000);
            p1score = 0;
            p2score = 0;
            target = 10;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to solve it by dividing the logic between priming for a answer, and then waiting for the input to the answer, if anyone is interested:

```
// Squash Scorer, by @MrWigster
            // Squash scoring is fairly easy for the most part, however at 10-10 the first player to have reached 10 must decide whether to play until 13 or 15, as the winner must always have a 2 point lead.
            // For this reason we need to include logic to let the players choose what score to play until, always in either incremenets of 2 || 4. EG: 13 || 15, 17 || 19 etc.

            //To Do :
            // * Set/Games Counter
            // Function for score incrementing to help respect DRY coding
            #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
            LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
            //Setting up Switches, 1 for each player to press.
            const int player1switch = 7;
            const int player2switch = 6;
            //Setting up LEDs, 1 representing each player.
            const int led1 = 9;
            const int led2 = 10;
            //Players names
            String player1 = "Hraday";
            String player2 = "Alex";
            int switchStatePlayer1 = 0;
            int switchStatePlayer2 = 0;
            int targetChosen = 1;
            int decideTarget = 1;
            int p1score = 0;
            int p2score = 0;
            int winner;
            // Initial Target score to get to
            int target = 11;

            void setup() {
                Serial.begin(9600);
                lcd.begin(16,2);
                pinMode(player1switch,INPUT);
                pinMode(player2switch,INPUT);
                pinMode(led1,OUTPUT);
                pinMode(led2,OUTPUT);
                lcd.print(player1);
                lcd.print(" Vs ");
                lcd.print(player2);
                lcd.setCursor(0,1);
                lcd.print("SquashScorer 0.1");
            }

            void loop() {



                // If LED is still on, turn it off.
                if((digitalRead(led1) == HIGH) || (digitalRead(led2) == HIGH)){
                    delay(200);
                digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
                digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
                }




                // If players scores are the same, and it's at the target score to change
                if (targetChosen == 0){
                    lcd.clear();
                    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
                    // Give the players the info about which score they can choose
                    lcd.print(target + 2);
                    lcd.print("    OR    ");
                    lcd.print(target + 4);
                    targetChosen = 1;
                    decideTarget = 0;
                }
                // While new target score hasn't been decided, keep checking.
                while(decideTarget == 0) {
                        newTarget();
                }
                if((targetChosen == 1) && (decideTarget == 1)) {
                    switchStatePlayer1 = digitalRead(player1switch);
                    if(switchStatePlayer1 == HIGH){
                        digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
                        p1score = p1score++;
                        if ((p1score == target - 1) && (p2score == target - 1)) { targetChosen = 0; }
                        //Deciding if this was winning point
                        if ((p1score == target) || (p2score == target) && (p1score != p2score)) {
                            winner = whoWins(player1);
                        }
                        Serial.println("New Score__________");
                        Serial.println(p1score);
                        newScore();
                    }
                    switchStatePlayer2 = digitalRead(player2switch);
                    if(switchStatePlayer2 == HIGH){
                        digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
                        p2score = p2score++;
                        if ((p1score == target - 1) && (p2score == target - 1)) { targetChosen = 0; }
                        //Deciding if this was winning point
                        if ((p1score == target) || (p2score == target) && (p1score != p2score)) {
                            winner = whoWins(player2);
                        }
                        Serial.println("New Score__________");
                        Serial.println(p2score);
                        newScore();
                    }
                }
            }
            int newTarget(){
                Serial.println(decideTarget);
                Serial.println("Waiting for input...");
                if(digitalRead(player1switch) == HIGH){
                    target = target + 2;
                    newScore();
                    decideTarget = 1;
                    delay(250);
                }
                if(digitalRead(player2switch) == HIGH){
                    target = target + 4;
                    newScore();
                    decideTarget = 1;
                    delay(250);
                }
            }
            void newScore(){
                lcd.clear();
                lcd.setCursor(0,0);
                lcd.print(player1);
                lcd.print("      ");
                lcd.print(player2);
                lcd.setCursor(0,1);
                lcd.print(p1score);
                lcd.print(" Target:");
                lcd.print(target);
                lcd.print("  ");
                lcd.print(p2score);
                Serial.println("NewScore() Called");
            }
            void ledflash(){
                for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
                    digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
                    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
                    delay(500);
                    digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
                    digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
                    delay(500);
                }
                digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
                digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
            }
            int whoWins(String player){
                lcd.clear();
                lcd.setCursor(0,0);
                lcd.print(player);
                lcd.setCursor(0,1);
                lcd.print("is the Winner!");
                ledflash();
                delay(3000);
                p1score = 0;
                p2score = 0;
                target = 10;
            }
```